# Python3 print variable inside brackets

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

I found a project on github that someone put a lot of effort into, my thinking is if they put this much effort into this software, it must work somehow, but I am unable to get it to work.

vprint

```
def vprint(*args, **kwargs):
    if verbose:
         print(*args, **kwargs)
```

It has lines like

```
  vprint("    {file}")
```

and right about that line is the variable 'file', but it does not print the contents of that variable, it literally prints

```
      {file}
```

How do I get python to interpret the variables inside of the brackets?

Comment: vprint is not a built-in function or a well-known extension in python, so you should have given a link to the whole source for one to fully help. That said, you might want to take a look at [f-strings](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is interpolated strings:

```
print(f"    {file}")
```

Literal string interpolation was added in Python 3.6 <sup>[1](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/), [2](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/string-interpolation)</sup>: such strings are referred to as *f-strings*, taken from the leading character (f) used to denote such strings, and standing for "formatted strings".

F-strings generally offer an improved, less cumbersome, more flexible and faster way to format strings in python  <sup>[1](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/), [2](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/string-interpolation), [3](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/#f-strings-a-new-and-improved-way-to-format-strings-in-python)</sup>. The referenced links include several examples of such strings.

F-strings aren't constant values but expressions that are evaluated at runtime. This allows us to do more powerful formatting, such as inline arithmetic:

```py
a = 12
b = 3
print(f'12 multiply 3 is {a * b}.')
```

The output would be:

> 12 multiply 3 is 36.

Comment: Is there some way to enable that? I am using python 3.7.4 and its not processing the variables inside the brackets

Comment: vprint is just a wrapper of print, there is nothing to vprint, it just allows you to turn off print... and file is a file retireved from a directory

Comment: What result do you have when you call `print(file)`?

Comment: it prints a filepath

Comment: If you make sure there is an `f` in front of the formatting string, then `f"{file}"` will automatically get turned into a string containing your file name. Try `print(f"{file}")`.